# Calling function if mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wordpress

I'm completely lost when it comes to jQuery/Javascript so apologies in advance. I'm using the [MixItUp jQuery filter](http://mixitup.io/) on a Wordpress site which has the option to show either grid or list view (default), what I'd like to do is [set grid](http://mixitup.io/#ToGrid) as default when visiting the site using a mobile device.

This is what I have at the moment (I've been copying and pasting from around the web so probably not even close):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Grid').mixitup('toGrid');
});
```

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the "if" statement and function call inside the document ready call. Not the other way around:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $('#Grid').mixitup({layoutMode : 'grid'});
    }


});
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work unfortunately. Is there an easy way for me to debug this? Using an Android phone to test it on but not sure how to debug.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm not familiar with that particular plugin, but I'd break the troubleshooting down into three parts: 1. is your mixitup implementation working on desktop systems? 2. is it working on your mobile browser? 3. Is your function to detect mobile devices working? Start by commenting out the "if" clause and its closing brace and run it on a desktop system. If it works, try the same thing on your mobile. If it doesn't work on the desktop system use firebug or chrome devtools to debug the JS.

Comment: Great thanks, will go through the steps and let you know what I come up with!

Answer (score 0):

I have messed with detecting if a device is mobile or not a lot in the past and I have found it to be much easier to detect if it is **not** a mobile device versus detecting if it is a mobile device.

I like the searches you are doing, but you are missing a few like the Nook and Kindle a lot of mobile devices also use the word "mobile" in their user agent. With that said even if you include these in your search you will surely have more that pop up over the next few years. I have found it to be better to detect if it is a desktop or not because there are not new desktop operating systems being added on almost a yearly basis like we are seeing with mobile devices these days. Not only that but I have also found that older Android devices can return mixed results in their user agents.

Here is the bit of code we use to figure out if the device is Windows, Linux, Mac, Facebook, a bot, or a mobile device. We have used and tested this code a lot with all the different devices we have vising our site and it appears to be working correctly for all devices. I hope this helps!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if (deviceType() == "Mobile")
          $('#Grid').mixitup('toGrid');
});


function deviceType ()
{
     var OSName="Mobile";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Phone")===-1) OSName="Windows";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Macintosh")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Android")===-1) OSName="Linux";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("facebook.com")!=-1) OSName="facebook";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("bot")!=-1) OSName="bot";
     if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Slerp")!=-1) OSName="bot";
     return OSName;
}
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks a bunch! Will definitely come in handy. However, I think the issue here might be that the actual function for setting the grid isn't working. Any help on that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I just took a quick look at the documentation for that plugin and edited my original answer.

Comment: No change unfortunately. Not sure how this works so please correct me if I'm wrong - the document ready function calls the below method on page load? Or does $('#Grid').mixitup('toGrid'); need to be triggered somehow?

Also, in case it might help - I've attached below link to the page: [link](http://vetojuicers.com/site/recipes/)